# What racks will fit on a Pugsley?

Tags: cargo, rack, off-road

So I have a [Surly Pugsley](http://surlybikes.com/frames/pugsley_frame/) which I love dearly.  I want to add a rack to it so that I can do simple "grocery getter" tasks on my way to and from work, but I'm afraid that standard racks will not work because of the special nature of the frame.

Are there any racks out there that will work with a Pugsley?  Are there any modifications that need to be made for them to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll leave it to others to post a full answer, but I found [this page](http://thelazyrando.wordpress.com/2009/06/19/surly-pugsley-rack-options/) about this very topic.

Comment: Nobody else posted an answer? That's too bad; we're trying to avoid answers than comprise of only a link. @Jack, if someone posts a better answer than this, please feel free to reassign the "correct" answer to them. :)

Answer (score 2):

I just installed the surly nice rack. had to spread it open slightly for the front offset fork but other than that it bolts on easily with the surly mount kit